# Nested queries Firebase Firestore for Android Java

Tags: java, android, sql, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How to use subqueries in Firestore like in sql?

For example, I have:

UserChat:

- userId
- chatId

Chat:

- id
- storeId

Store:

- id
- name

How can I get the name of the members of the class?
In sql it would be something like

`SELECT name FROM Store WHERE id IN (SELECT storeId FROM Chat where id IN (SELECT chatId from UserChat where userId = 'aa') )`

Something like that but in Firestore in Android Java. Maybe the query is wrong but it's invented , so forgive me.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase does not support any joins or nested subqueries.  A query is limited to only a single collection at a time.  You will have to perform multiple queries and merge the data on the client.

Comment: And that is as fast as or  closer to Sql nested queries??

Comment: Performance isn't the issue.  Firestore queries scale with the number of documents that you get from the query - they are insanely fast at scale. The issue is that you simply have to do your queries this way, or restructure your data (denormalize) in such a way that reduces your queries.